# React flexbox is overflowing screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to get a `div` to render until the bottom of the screen/page (and no further than that).

I'm able to do that successfully as long as this `div` is the only thing in the entire page. However, it's overflowing the page whenever I have anything above it (in this example, the text `Some Header`).

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bird-phx1f?file=/src/App.js

[image]

The React code:

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { Fragment } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>Some Header</div>
      <div className="test1">
        <div className="dashbar">Dash</div>
        <div className="other-content">Other</div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

The CSS code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.test1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.dashbar {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.other-content {
  flex: 1 0 90%;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

How can I make it so that this `div` will stop at the bottom of the page and not overflow like this?

If I remove `<div>Some Header</div>`, then it behaves as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.test1` has a height of 100vh, meaning you are forcing it to be exactly as tall as the viewport. But it has a header above it! So, the header necessarily pushes it down and it overflows the screen. You need a bit more of Flexbox trickery to get it right, especially `flex-grow:1`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#root {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.dashbar {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.other-content {
  flex: 1 0 90%;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div>
      Some Header<br>
      with a couple<br>
      of lines in it
    </div>
    <div class="test1">
      <div class="dashbar">Dash</div>
      <div class="other-content">Other</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That works but what should I do if I don't want to wrap my entire page in a single div? I just want this component to be at the bottom of the page and fill up whatever remaining space there happens to be

Comment: Yep, that's the point of `flex-grow:1`, it means "Use whatever space remains"

Answer (score 0):

It's because "test1" has height as 100vh and there is a static header text which has some height. Try this to fix:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.test1 {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 15px);
  border: 10px solid green;
}
```

--- Dynamic solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-agnesi-x496f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That only works if the header is static. What if its height is dynamic? I'd really like a dynamic solution.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-agnesi-x496f?file=/src/App.js